# How do I extract the formula for an octave/matlab interpolation?

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting

So, I have some points:

```
## Some points
x = [1  2  3  4  5  6 ];
y = [10 15 30 45 50 55];
```

and I can fit a curve to them:

```
x1 = linspace(1,6);

# piecewise cubic hermite interpolating polynomial, respects monotonicity.
pchipy1 = interp1(x,y,x1,"pchip");
```

and plot the curve:

```
plot(x1,pchipy1);
```

And now people are saying to me: ***"My, that is a nice curve, what is the formula for it?"***

And I have no answer.

But I am thinking that this is just a spline curve, made up of cubic pieces, so at the very least it should be possible to get formulae for the pieces?

Anyone know how?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html

Comment: Thanks @Cris, that's actually a full answer to my question. I think I'll type up the details to answer the question based on this. Unless you'd like to?

Answer (score 2):

The formula is written in the MATLAB [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html#bvjbxbd-pp):

f(x) = a*(x−x1)^3 + b*(x−x1)^2 + c*(x−x1) + d

Only, `interp1`, won't return the fitted coefficients. As @Cris Luengo mentioned, the function that is called under the hood is [`pchip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html). So if you want to have the coefficients, you'll need to call `pchip` and [`ppval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ppval.html) afterwards to create your own 1D-interpolation.

```matlab
% vq = interp1(x,y,x1,"pchip") =>
pp = pchip(x,y);
pchipy1  = ppval(pp,x1);
```

The [documentation on octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/pchip.html) is not so elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, you and Cris have solved my problem! It seems a sufficiently useful question that I think I'll type up the details to make a full answer with an example. Unless you or Chris would like to do it? In which case I'll accept that as *the* answer.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden just checked the Octave docs. They don't state much on the underlying theory. I recommend to consult the MATLAB docs for such things. They pretty much get payed for the docs ('cause engineers are not comfortable in reading blog-posts ;) )

Comment: “'cause engineers are not comfortable in reading blog-posts” Or rather because they understand that software is only as useful (and therefore valuable) as its documentation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo fully agree this is not a very good 'defense' of octave on this point, but I _have_ found that there is typically a wealth of information (e.g. equations, derivations, and academic references) in the 'source' code of most functions of this type. This is also true for pchip.

Comment: @Tasos: I should look at the sources more. Octave is made by very knowledgeable people, I'm sure we can all learn a lot from them. But documentation is just one of those things that programmers are not good at doing, you really need to pay people to have them write docs! :) (And I can say this because I'm not good at writing docs either.)